# Where do I plug in power for my video card?

Tags: graphics-card

I'm building my first computer, and the video card I have is [MSI R6670-MD1GD5 Radeon HD 6670](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127586). I was watching a video that said you needed to plug in a cord to supply power to it, but I can't find where to plug it in.  Does the motherboard supply power for this card or what?

Comment: I don't see it either, and none of the spec sheets mention it. Maybe the video is wrong?

Comment: @Amazed I suspect the video may have been about video cards in general as opposed to this specific one.

Comment: @Synetech inc. most likely, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only high-powered graphics cards require a second rail for power beyond what is provided by the PCI connection.

It looks like neither of the R6670-MD1GD5 need any additional power, and so no connector is present on the card to accept it.

So yes, the motherboard provides all the power needed for this card.